# Some problems regarding removing a child added dynamically

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have this function where I want to get a movie clip (the function target) and change it to another one. The problem is that it obviously removes the movie clip before the new one is loaded.

```
var changePeca:Loader = new Loader;
var changeLoad:URLRequest = new URLRequest(e.target.name.substr(0,4)+".png");
changePeca.load(changeLoad);

e.target.removeChildAt(0);
e.target.addChild(changePeca);
```

I know that I must use the `Event.COMPLETE` thing, but how do I say which movie clip to remove, since I cant use `e.target` anymore?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do, can you elaborate more?

Comment: store reference in some additional object , like : var current:DisplayObject = e.target , than use it from other function

Comment: you show show additional code, for example, where `e.target` is coming from

Comment: Yeah sorry, e.target is coming from a MouseEvent. So I have this movie clip on stage, Im adding tons of movie clips, and when I click one of then he changes into another img. I just tried to hold the movieclip name with a string and find it later trought getChildByName, but looks like that isnt possible as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "The problem is that it obviously removes the movie clip before the new
>   one is loaded."

Because you code says do so! :) You need to add the event listener which checks if the stuff is loaded.

```
private var holderMC:Sprite;
private var imageLoader:Loader;

private  function load(e:Event):void
{
    holderMC = e.target as Sprite // or something else you have there, just store it.
    imageLoader = new Loader ();
    imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleLoadComplete)
    imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(e.target.name.substr(0, 4) + ".png"));
}

private function handleLoadComplete(e:Event):void 
{
    if(holderMC.numChildren > 0)
        holderMC.removeChildAt(0);

    holderMC.addChild(imageLoader.content)
}
```